# Como obter acesso aos métodos onView, withId ou matches no Android?

Tags: android, testes-de-unidade, junit

[Estou seguindo este tutorial !](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html)

Nele, exibe este exemplo:

```
package com.example.android.testing.espresso.BasicSample;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
...

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class ChangeTextBehaviorTest {

    private String mStringToBetyped;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
            MainActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void initValidString() {
        // Specify a valid string.
        mStringToBetyped = "Espresso";
    }

    @Test
    public void changeText_sameActivity() {
        // Type text and then press the button.
        onView(withId(R.id.editTextUserInput))
                .perform(typeText(mStringToBetyped), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.changeTextBt)).perform(click());

        // Check that the text was changed.
        onView(withId(R.id.textToBeChanged))
                .check(matches(withText(mStringToBetyped)));
    }
}
```

Fiz todos os passos , mas na minha classe não tem estes métodos: `onView`  `withId` ou `matches`

Como faço para que ter acesso a estes métodos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui adicionando os seguintes *import´s*:

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.*;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.*;
```

Sendo estes *import´s* estáticos, os métodos tornam se acessíveis a classe